# PHP ajax post big data handling

Tags: php, ajax

I am having problem in posting PHP (CI) from the view to controller. Have been surfing internet for quite a while but can't find any solution. I know that the maximum 1000 variable can be extended in the php.ini file(if i am not mistaken).

my form code

```
<?php 
  $i = 0;
   foreach($data as $r){
     if(!$r['supply']){
      $i++;
      echo " 
      <tr>
        <td> <input type='text' class='form-control' name='index_number[]' value='".$r['index_number']."' placeholder='Index Number' readonly>  </td>
        <td> <input type='text' class='form-control' name='code[]' value='".$r['product_code']."' placeholder='Product Code' readonly>  </td>
        <td> <textarea style='resize:none'; rows='4' cols='50' readonly class='form-control' name='description[]' placeholder='Product Description'> ".$r['product_description']."</textarea> </td>
        <td> <input type='text' class='form-control' name='qty[]' value='".$r['product_qty']."' placeholder='Qty' readonly>  </td>
        <td> <input type='text' class='form-control' name='uom[]' value='".$r['product_uom']."' placeholder='UOM' readonly>  </td>
        <td> <input type='text' class='form-control' name='price[]' value='".$r['product_price']."' placeholder='Price'> </td>
        <td> <textarea style='resize:none'; rows='4' cols='50' class='form-control' name='remarks[]' placeholder='Product Remarks'> ".$r['product_remarks']."</textarea> </td>
        <td> <input type='hidden' name='product_id[]' value='".$r['product_id']."'></td>
    </tr>
    ";
}
}
?>
```

my ajax function

```
<script>
    function postData(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "<?php echo base_url('url/processForm') ?>",
            cache: false,    
            data: $('#quotationRequest').serialize(),
            success: function(response){  
                $("body").html(response);
            },
            error: function(){      
                alert('Error while request..');
            }
        });
    }
 </script>
```

How to write an ajax code that will post the data from the PHP view to controller per 100 data? So in total, the ajax will post data 10 times (total 1000 data).

Thank you

Comment: Are you asking how to write a loop in javascript? Or how to split the data? Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: How can i post the divided data(100 data) from the PHP view to controller using ajax.. that is my problem Sir.. sorry for the confusion

Comment: I think he means that the current `$('#quotationRequest').serialize()` is generating more then 1000 variables? If thats the case, you're doing something wrong.